# Changed Core Data Model Without Having Versioning Turned On

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, database-migration, core-data-migration

I have changed my Core Data model a bit (set some attributes as `optional` and `non-optional`).

Unfortunately I did not turn automatic versioning on...

I have uploaded my App to the App Store yesterday and it is still under review by Apple. 
I am afraid that it will break existing installations of my app.

This is why I would like to cancel my currently uploaded Binary and reset my Core Data model to the previous attributes settings and then upload the App again.

This leads me to the following questions:

- How is determined if the current data model is compatible with the
  existing one? Is this being done purely on a comparison of attributes
  or by comparing the `systemVersion` in the contents file of the Core
  Data model?
- How can I solve my problem and avoid that the new version of my App
  will lead to crashes due to an incompatible data model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compatible versions are determined by matching version numbers.

Solve by doing exactly what you propose. Pull the binary, revert your changes, version the model, remake your changes, ensure that auto-migration is enabled and test that it works correctly.

The version number is created by generating a 32-byte hash digest of the components which are compared for equality:

> - For each entity the following attributes must be equal: **name**, **parent**, **isAbstract**, and **properties**.
>     **className**, **userInfo**, and **validation predicates** are not compared.
> - For each property in each entity, the following attributes must be equal: **name**, **isOptional**, **isTransient**, **isReadOnly**, for attributes **attributeType**, and for relationships **destinationEntity**, **minCount**, **maxCount**, **deleteRule**, and **inverseRelationship**.
>     **userInfo** and **validation predicates** are not compared.

[Apple ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmUnderstandingVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH2-SW1)

Technically, if you don't change anything that doesn't affect the version number then you don't need to version the model. Note that your change will impact the version number so you do need to take action.

Comment: Is it ok when I set the attributes manually in the model editor or do I need to restore the model from Git? I would prefer the first solution.

Comment: Restoring from GIT will reset everything. Each time you change something in the model the version number changes. I don't know if changing something and then changing it back resets the version number - I guess not...

Comment: But how does Core Data know if the model has changed? Is it checking the version number or is it comparing the attributes?